# Extension for Array in Swift to read an array from plist using NSPropertyListReadOptions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

I am trying to implement an extension to the Array in Swift to be able to initialised from a plist file, I am trying to use `NSPropertyListReadOptions`

```
extension Array {
  static func arrayFromPlistWithName (filename: String) -> [[String:AnyObject]]? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "plist")!
    let url  = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    let opts  = NSPropertyListReadOptions(rawValue: NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves.rawValue)
    let plist = try! NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data!, options: opts, format: nil)

    return plist as? [[String:AnyObject]]
   }
}
```

and here how I use it:

```
    let a:[[String:AnyObject]]? = Array.arrayFromPlistWithName("countries")
```

but I can an error :

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]?' to specified type '[[String : AnyObject]]?'
```

My question is how to make it work and how also to handle all errors because I use a lot of force unwrapping which may be a cause of crashes

Comment: BTW: you can use [`URLForResource(_:ofType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:) to get an `NSURL` directly, instead of manually creating one from a `String`

Comment: NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData creates a plist file from the given data, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
enum ArrayFromPlistError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidPlist
}  

extension Array { 

    static func readArray(FromPlistNamed name: String) throws -> [AnyObject] {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "plist")!

        if let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile:path) {
            return array as AnyObject as! [AnyObject]
        }
        else {
            throw ArrayFromPlistError.InvalidPlist
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After correcting your code: `ErrorType` instead of `ErrorProtocol` and `name `instead of `filename` I get this error :  `Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred` when try to using like `let c = try! Array.readArrayFromPlistNamed("filename")`

Comment: Whoops, it's `ErrorProtocol` in Swift 3 :) try: `let c: [AnyObject] = try! Array.readArrayFromPlistNamed("filename")`

Comment: thx for the replay I get `Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to specified type '[AnyObject]'` when trying your last suggestion

Comment: Interesting... I wonder if anyone else will be able to help out